# Flow divs into rows

Tags: css, rows

I'm trying to get these DIVs to "flow" from left to right in sets of two, then for every odd one, make a new row in my client's Joomla site (seen here http://centralcat.socialhippo.com/services/available-for-adoption.html
I've got the first two working, but when the third one is rendered, it goes to the right instead of being floated to the left.
I'm not married to the CSS so if there's a better way (list, etc.) I'll give it a try.

Comment: Just as a random aside, in the menu, when you click "About Us" or "Feline Health", it should probably take you somewhere (same place as the first link in the dropdown) instead of doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a height to `#cat2adopt` to fix this problem quickly. Just make sure the height is big enough to accommodate the content. this "problem" occurs when you have floated divs with varying heights.

You should also be using classes here, as IDs must be unique.

eg:

```
.cat2adopt { /* class="cat2adopt" */
    clear: right; /* don't really need this I don't think */
    float: left;
    height: 300px; /* added this */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't even notice it was an ID, I'll change that too (no sleep and too much coding).

Comment: I should add - if you don't want to work with fixed heights, you would need to add `clear:left;` to every "odd" `div` (3/5/7 etc). This could be achieved with Jquery or similar quite easily, but for a quick, painless fix, the above would be my recommendation

Comment: If you know the maximum number of lines the text can be, you should use an explicit height as per the answer. However, if the amount of text can vary wildly, you should use the jQuery solution in his comment.

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't believe I didn't think of that in all my tests, I must be more tired than I thought. :)